# jquery mobile navbar icons appearing in circle

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using custom icons but they're appearing in a circle. Is here a class I need to turn off to stop this?

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="top">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" id="test1" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn-active">
                                <span class="foot_font">test1</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="page40.html" id="test2" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                                <span class="foot_font">test2</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="page44.html" id="test3" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                                <span class="foot_font">test3</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="page22.html" id="test4" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                                <span class="foot_font">test4</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="page47.html" id="test5" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span">
                                <span class="foot_font">test5</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this css behavior by adding

```
.ui-icon
{
    border-radius:0px!important;
    -moz-border-radius:0px!important;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px!important;
    -ms-border-radius:0px!important;
    -o-border-radius:0px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the circle gray background behind simply add the

```
ui-nodisc-icon
```

class to the link/button

for example, your code can be changed to

```
<a href="#" id="test1" data-theme="e" data-icon="custom" data-corners="false" data-iconshow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn-active ui-nodisc-icon">
    <span class="foot_font">test1</span>
</a>
```